# font face not working in local not in server

Tags: html, css, amazon-s3, fonts, font-face

I used `font-face`, and it is not working. I used the following code in internal CSS:

```
@font-face {
font-family: acme;
src: url(https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/mailer-reach-on-time/ACMESecretAgentBB_BoldItal.otf);
}
```

My html code is below:

```
<p style="text-align:center; font-family: acme; font-size:28px; color: #4D4B4B;">TYPICAL MEETING ROOM</p>
```

When I use this in local it works fine, but when upload the fonts to the server and when I get the fonts from the server it won't work. Please anyone give a solution for this.

Comment: is your website https enabled? because you are loading font from https server

Comment: if not it will give cross origin error

Answer (score 1):

Retrieving the font from that Amazon S3 URL results in the [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) error below. Note that the `null` is just there because I'm testing from a stack snippet. In your case, it will most likely be replaced with your domain.

> Access to Font at
>   'https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/mailer-reach-on-time/ACMESecretAgentBB_BoldItal.otf'
>   from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

To be able to retrieve your font, you need to configure cross-origin resource sharing on your S3 bucket, as described [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html) in the Amazon S3 documentation.

The following configuration allows GET requests to all origins (which might be too liberal, depending on the contents of your bucket):

```
<CORSConfiguration>
 <CORSRule>
   <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
   <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
 </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Answer (score -2):

Use this code. It should work perfectly

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'acme';
  src: url('https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/mailer-reach-on-time/ACMESecretAgentBB_BoldItal.otf');  
}
```

```html
<p style="text-align:center; font-family: 'acme', arial; font-size:28px; color: #4D4B4B;">TYPICAL MEETING ROOM</p>
```

Comment: That's not a solution. You're just falling back on Arial.